# How to make required field in react dynamically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-final-form, final-form

Could you please tell me how to make a field required dynamically?

I have two fields `firstName` and `lastName`. **First name is required**. I want `lastName` to become a **required field** if I type `test` in **firstName**.

Is it possible?

Here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-pike-5k7jn

```
 <Field
            name="lastName"
            validate={values.firstName === "test" ? required : ""}
          >
            {({ input, meta }) => (
              <div>
                <label>Last Name</label>
                <input {...input} type="text" placeholder="Last Name" />
                {meta.error && meta.touched && <span>{meta.error}</span>}
              </div>
            )}
          </Field>
```

**Can I make the second field required only if user types `test` in *first name* field?**

API link

https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/examples

To see it not working reproduce these steps:

1) click submit button. It shows firstname is required.

2) enter test text in first name field.

3) press submit button again.

It is not showing required error. Why?

Comment: You have a syntax error on line 5 of index.js in https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-pike-5k7jn

Answer (score 3):

instead of putting field-level validation you can put validation in the Form tag

```
   <Form
      onSubmit={onSubmit}
      validate={values => {
        const errors = {};
        if (!values.firstName) {
          errors.firstName = "Required";
        }
        if (!values.lastName && values.firstName === "test") {
          errors.lastName = "Required";
        }
        return errors;
      }}
```

here is the [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-wilson-9ej79) of modified version of your codesandbox

Answer (score 1):

This is because your

```
<Field name = "lastName/>
```

props does not update in real time. You can try console.log(values.firstName) inside the validate function to confirm this.
To get around this my way is quite a hack, just add key = {values.firstName} to Field component like this

```
<Field key = {values.firstName} name = "lastName" validate = {values.firstName === "test" ? required : ""}> 
...renderStuffs
</Field>
```